# PostgreSQL: trying to retrieve yesterday's count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the number of bookings from yesterday. Here  is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct be.booking_id) AS "Number of Bookings Approved Today",
       TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as "id"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.event IN ('approve', 'instant_approve') AND
      be.created_at > TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' AND
      be.created_at < TIMESTAMP 'today'
GROUP BY be.created_at;
```

Right now, above code wont let me view the actual count of the number of bookings from yesterday. Rather it retrieves all the rows like this:

```
Date           # of bookings
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
<yesterday's date>       1
```

I want it to return the total count for yesterday's date like this:

```
Date,          # of bookings
<yesterday's date>       7
```

Hope somebody is able to help me out. It's probably an easy fix, but I can't wrap my brain around it!

Comment: Try changing your `group by` clause to `TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` I'm guessing it's a timestamp that contains time data too which screws up the grouping.

Comment: I just did that on my own using `GROUP BY 2`. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `be.created_at` is a timestamp with a time part?

Try changing your `group by` clause to `TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` so that the grouping is done by the date part only. Or you could use `group by` with an ordinal value indicating the column from the select statement to group by: `group by 2` (for the second column - the date in your sample query).

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I just had to `GROUP BY 2`. @jpw commented the reasoning behind it!